# How to make an input field required before being able to click a input button rather a submit button?

Tags: html, forms

I have a question about making input fields required before being able to click a input button (not submit button). My code below only will send out the requirement notice after a submit button is click.

I have my form split into 3 div's with 'next' buttons in between which conditionally displays the next div. How do I make the input field to be required before the 'next' button brings up the next div portion of my form?

Comment: My code below?? But where is the code

Comment: put some code what you have right now.

Answer (score 0):

You should post the html for your question. It is missing. That being said, look into the blur event that gets trigger everytime an input loses focus. You could add the logic to display an error to the user and disable the next button.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_blur.asp

Answer (score 0):

You have two main options:

**FIRST OPTION**

You could disable your button like so: `<input id="but" type="button" disabled>`, and then, you could set your field onchange method to enable the button i. e. `<input type="text" onchange="changed();">` and in your script,

```
function changed(){

  if(1 == 1){ // custom test
    document.getElementById("but").disabled = false;
  }

}
```

**SECOND OPTION**

In your button handler, verify your textfield is filled i. e.

```
function butHandler(){

  if(document.getElementById("textfield").value !== "") {
      // do your actions
  }

}
```